# How can I disable scroll lock (for LibreOffice Calc)?

Tags: keyboard, libreoffice

Scroll lock appears to be stuck on. This is only affecting me because LibreOffice Calc, when scroll lock is activated, responds to arrow keys by scrolling instead of changing which cell is selected, which is quite frustrating to me because I rely on the arrow keys to quickly navigate and edit sheets.

Here are some commands I've tried, with no effect on Calc's behavior (several were suggestions from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127167/how-do-i-enable-scroll-lock) and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764405/scroll-lock-does-not-work)):

- `xdotool key Scroll_Lock`
- `xset -led named "Scroll Lock"`
- `xset -led 3`
- `xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Scroll_Lock'`

I'm running Ubuntu 22 and LibreOffice 7.3.5.2.

I don't have a scroll lock button or LED on my laptop, but I have tried plugging in an external keyboard with one; the scroll lock key didn't change Calc's behavior and the LED on that keyboard stayed lit.

Some of the options above changed whether `xset q` listed scroll lock as on or off, but that still didn't correlate to Calc behaving.

Been struggling with this for a while, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure how many solutions or commands you've tried but, even though they involve older versions of LibreOffice, do any of the ones listed in the pages linked to below help? :-) https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272396/cannot-disable-scroll-lock-in-libreoffice-calc-using-a-dell-xps https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-to-disable-scroll-lock-feature-in-calc/24741/5

Comment: Switching keyboard layouts (the 1st link) worked! Sort-of anyway, when I switch back the problem returns, but at least I can use Calc in a different layout. Thanks for the quick reply! I haven't tried any of the suggestions about editing conf files, I was worried I'd mess things up worse.

Answer (score 5):

I had to deal with the same issue after upgrading Ubuntu from 20.10 to 22.04 on a QWERTY Thinkpad I often use with an AZERTY keyboard. I tried the same commands you did, and since I could not get used to switching layouts just for using Calc, I tried one of the solutions in the first link posted by **ardvark71** :

[cannot disable scroll lock in libreoffice-calc (using a dell xps)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272396/cannot-disable-scroll-lock-in-libreoffice-calc-using-a-dell-xps)

which was removing 'grp_led:scroll' from `dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options`, and that's done by entering this line in a terminal :

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['grp:alt_shift_toggle', 'numpad:microsoft']"
```

That did the trick ! Scroll Lock is disabled, and doesn't seem to enable itself after reboot.

Can't thank **ardvark71** and **nonNumericalFloat** enough for this one.

Comment: Thanks! That helped me too.

Answer (score 0):

> but I have tried plugging in an external keyboard with one

Without also changing the underlying keyboard selected in `Settings` to match the newly pugged in keyboard, that is to be expected.

As to setting/unsetting <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> on (typically) laptops not fitted with a physical key,  some of these key combinations have a secondary function  that acts as if a <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> key condition is pressed. Some common methods are:

- <kbd>Fn+S</kbd> or <kbd>Fn+F6</kbd> on certain Dell laptops.
- <kbd>Fn+C</kbd> or <kbd>Fn+K</kbd> on certain Lenovo laptops.
- <kbd>Fn+C</kbd> on certain HP laptops.

[reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scroll_Lock)